# Why are my references at the bottom of the page?

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

This is how my main tex file looks like:

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math


\begin{document}
...
\cite{abst}
...    
\section{\label{sec:level1}References}

\bibliography{bibtex.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

and this is how my references are shown:

[image]

I want the references to be in the same style of the rest of the text (without the line above and apart from the rest of the text). Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The `revtex4-1` document class is well-known for making a number of, shall we say, idiosyncratic document layout choices. One of them is placing the formatted bibliography below the running text, separated from the running text by a horizontal bar. With this document class, it's neither necessary nor advisable to provide a section-level header, numbered or unnumbered, named "References". You are presumably using the `revtex4-1` document class because you're supposed to use it. Just learn to live with its design choices -- you'll get used to them fairly quickly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. But the copy editors of the journal you're submitting the paper to will not be happy.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title A},
  journal={Journal A},
  year=2018,
}
@article{b,
  author={A. Buthor},
  title={Title B},
  journal={Journal B},
  year=2018,
}
@article{c,
  author={A. Cuthor},
  title={Title C},
  journal={Journal C},
  year=2018,
}
@article{d,
  author={A. Duthor},
  title={Title D},
  journal={Journal D},
  year=2018,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[reprint,aps]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
  \par\mbox{}%
  \section{\label{sec:level1}References}%
}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{A. Uthor}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-4]

Citations \cite{a,b,c,d} and a footnote\footnote{Footnote!}

\bibliographystyle{apsrmp4-1}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]